# What is the deep reason for the different speed between photon and electron?

Tags: special-relativity, photons, mass, speed-of-light, electrons

The photons travel at $c$, but electrons are slow(er). (I know photons could not interact with higgs boson field, but I don't think it's simple like that. Must be existing deeper reasons.) Also, why the photons are always move? Who let them move? It is like you grab a photon in vacuum, they will move by itself? Could a photon be still?

Comment: I recall reading that since a proton has zero mass, that it must always be moving at the speed of light through whatever medium it may be traveling through. An electron, which does have mass, could never travel at the same speed (the speed of light) as the photon.

Comment: The simple reason is that if we say that photon EXISTS, then it must move. Because if something exists, it must have ENERGY. Photon has zero rest mass, and so the only energy it can have is kinetic energy. Photon is an electromagnetic wave quanta; and it was shown by Maxwell that electromagnetic waves move at the speed 'c' in vacuum. Meaning the particle that represents that wave, the photon, also moves at that speed. Electron has no such requirements, since it has a non-zero rest mass.

Comment: @PrasadMani But why the EM wave travels at c? Also, all the particle has the wave-particle dualism, so the electron could also be considered as wave, why the electron wave is slower than the light wave?

Comment: Because electron wave (its wavefunction rather), is NOT an electromagnetic wave. But light wave is, as proved by maxwell; maxwell proved that electromagnetic wave happens to travel at the same speed at which light travelled (whose speed was measured to great accuracy by an experimental genius named Fizeau). Read up on Fizeau rotating wheel experiment.

Comment: @PrasadMani I agree with you. But I have another question. If an electron moves faster, then its relativistic energy will increase. In contract, when the relativistic energy of a photon is absorbed by an electron, it will move faster. So now, whether we could invent a new way of propulsion system by give the relativistic energy of photon to electron or other matter to accelerate them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Photons are different from massive particles. Their energy does not increase with velocity (which is constant in free space), rather it is dependent on the frequency of the electromagnetic oscillations.
If a massive body moves close to c, you are right, it will have enormous kinetic energy.